# Identify correct answer from <li> list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `questions` which have five `choices` of which one is TRUE for choices.is_correct.

I currently have an ERB loop displaying the question and possible answer choices, with choices randomize in an ordered list (`<li>`).

In a separate ERB loop, I need to display the correct answer in the form of it's respective `<li>` label (A,B,C,D or E).

I feel like this might be possible through some sort of local variable, but none of my tests are working so far. Should local variables work, or am I approaching from the wrong perspective?

My current ERB for the question / answer section:

```
      <%  @free_questions.each_with_index do |question, i| %>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <% @a = ("a".."z").to_a %>
            <h5>Question <%= i+1 %>: <%= question.name %></h5>
            <p>
            <ol type="A">
              <%  @free_choices.where(question: question.id).sort_by{rand}.each do |choice| %>
                <li><%= choice.name %></li>
              <% end %><br />
            </ol>
            </p>
            <%  @free_choices.where(question: question.id, correct: TRUE).each do |choice| %>
              <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">

                <%  if choice.question.context.present? or choice.question.image.attached? %>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="headingC<%= i+1 %>">
                      <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseC<%= i+1 %>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseC<%= i+1 %>">
                          CLICK FOR QUESTION CONTEXT
                        </button>
                      </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseC<%= i+1 %>" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingC<%= i+1 %>" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <p>
                          <%  if choice.question.image.attached? %>
                            <img src="<%= url_for(choice.question.image) if choice.question.image.attached? %>" class="rounded float-center" alt="context image for this question">
                          <% end %>
                          <!--TODO: Add more useful image alts here-->
                          <%= simple_format(choice.question.context) %>
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <% end %>    

                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header" id="headingA<%= i+1 %>">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                      <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseA<%= i+1 %>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseA<%= i+1 %>">
                        CLICK FOR ANSWER
                      </button>
                    </h5>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseA<%= i+1 %>" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingA<%= i+1 %>" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p>
                        Correct Answer: <b><%= choice.name %></b>
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        Explanation: <%= raw(choice.question.explanation) %>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            <% end %>
            <hr />
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

EDIT: Adding the models below

question.rb

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :assign_questionable
  belongs_to :questionable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :choices, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :choices, allow_destroy: true
```

choice.rb

```
class Choice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
```

Comment: Can you please share source of Question and Choice Models as well?

Comment: Sure thing - added the models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am outlining quick fix

1. replace `<% @a = ("a".."z").to_a %>` with `<% alpha_numbers = ("A".."Z").to_a %>`. You are using `<ol type="A">` which prints list in upper case latter not in small case.
2. Move above snippet outside `@free_questions.each_with_index` loop so that you don't end up initializing same array for each question in loop.
3. Replace `@free_choices.where(question: question.id).sort_by{rand}.each do |choice|` with `question.choices.shuffle.each_with_index do |choice, index|`. As per the model relationship, `question.choices` will give same result as `@free_choices.where(question: question.id)`. `shuffle` is better way of doing `sort_by{rand}`.
4. In the `Choice` model, add `attr_accessor :alpha_order`. This will create accessor methods.
5. Above `<li><%= choice.name %></li>` line add `<% choice.alpha_order = alpha_numbers[index] %>`. This line sets current alphabetic order of choice in an instance variable.
6. Replace `@free_choices.where(question: question.id, correct: TRUE).each do |choice|` with `question.choices.select { |choice| choice.is_correct }.each do`. This will loop through only those choices for given `question` where `is_correct` is `true`.
7. If you want to get alphabetic number attached to choice, access it using `choice.alpha_order` which will give correct alpha order.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're a legend, thanks for including details about why it does what also! I've implemented, and it's working great. :)

Comment: That's nice. Thanks!